# How to accurately get the contour of a shape in an image?

Tags: python, image, contour

I'm having black and white 93x94 pixel images with geometric shapes in them. I'm trying to find the shapes contours as well as their center

This is what I tried so far

```py
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 7, (0, 0, 0), -1)
    #cv2.putText(img, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
        #cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)

    # show the image
    cv2.imshow('output image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is a sample input image and output image with given contour and sample

Original image:

[image: original image]

Output image:

[image: Output image]

As you can see, instead of getting the contour and center of the shape, I'm getting those of the bounding box.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After blurring and thresholding, the image is almost completely white.

[image: After threasholding]

I'm not sure what I'd expect from that. Using a value of 160 does a better job here

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

The next problem is in using `RETR_EXTERNAL`, since

> retrieves only the extreme outer contours.

Using `RETR_TREE` seems right

> retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full hierarchy of nested contours.